# Calling methods from another class in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I know usually, when you want to call a method on another object, you do:

`NewObject *object = [NewObject alloc]init];`

`[object callMethod];`

But I created a class that isn't an object itself meaning it doesn't have properties or memory management.  It has a couple methods that calculate some stuff.

From any other class, all I have to do is import the header for this class and do:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

[MyClass callMethod];
```

Why in this case do I not have to alloc init? It works just fine.

Comment: they are called Class methods so you do not need to instantiate an object to call them.You need to init instances of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to call a class method.  These are methods which have been defined as:

- +(void) myStaticMethod;

instead of

- -(void) myMethod;

The plus sign indicates that the method does not use any fields, and thereby does not need to instantiate the object.

In your example, "object" is an instance of a class "NewObject" which has been allocated memory and initialized.  Where-as your example, "MyClass" is only a class which because it has static members declared as above, does not need to be instantiated.

Class methods provide a nice way to combine a bunch of related functions into one place, rather than having them spread out in the regular namespace, as would usually be done in straight C.  You can also have both class methods and instance methods in the same class, using the class ones when needed, and instantiating the class to use the instance ones when needed.

EDIT: Changed terminology to refer to class methods instead of static methods.

Comment: static and class methods are absolutely different things. ObjC does not have static methods.

Comment: Max, thanks for setting me straight.  I always referred to them as static methods as that is what C++ calls them, but I was using the wrong terminology for Objective C.  I have edited the response to correct.

Answer (score 1):

because you are calling a class method. You only need to `alloc init` objects. Classes only need to be included but not `alloc init`ed. So you don't need to init an `NSString` class, say.

Edit:

Let's just have some nonsense examples:

```
+ (void)classMethod {
    NSLog("Hi!");
}

[SomeClass classMethod];     // prints Hi!

- (void)instanceMethod {     // (say it's an instance method of NSString)
    NSLog(self);
}

[@"someNSString" instanceMethod];   // prints someNSString. But you need to have a string first, otherwise you cannot use this method.
```

Comment: The method I have is a class method, but it doesn't return anything.  What is the difference between a class and instance method when both don't return anything?

Comment: The difference is whether you apply that method to a class or to an object. For example, if you want to call `stringByAppendingString`, you want to call it on an existing `NSString` object. You cannot append a string to a class! On the other hand, if you want to get the current time, you don't need to have an object to get it. You can just call the `NSDate` class for that.

Comment: Oops sorry I should have given examples for not returning anything. Let's see. Lemme edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between "instance" methods (normal ones), that have to be called on an object and have access to `self`, and "class" methods (called static, in many programming languages), that are invoked on the class and thus do not have a `self`.

Comment: Oh ok.  So in my class, the class methods don't return anything.  Would I able to accomplish the same thing by making this class a singleton and then calling the method on that singleton from throughout the app?  Which is the better approach?

Comment: Class functions are a better choice than a singleton in that case. A singleton is a good choice if you have some variables that have to be shared between the various members; if you have just a lone method, use a class function.

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are similar to C++ static methods, in that they can be invoked without creating a concrete instance of the class. The usefulness of this is you can call a class's specialized factory methods to create a new instance; or, you can define a utility library under the scope of a class that may or may not provide concrete instances depending on the task.

Look at NSDate and NSNumber are good examples of this in the Foundation framework.